# Receive net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND message but working image link shows in HTML

Tags: javascript, file-not-found

I am putting together a weather app suing weatherapi.
I can retrieve the general weather but I get a net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND message for the icon, however the icon url shows in the HTML and is working when I open it in a new tab.
I also receive undefined for the temp and feelslike queries.

Any help would be appreciated please.

My javascript code below:

```js
const 
    search = document.getElementById("keyword"),
    submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-button"),
    cityName = document.getElementById("city"),
    showDate = document.getElementById("date"),
    showTime = document.getElementById("time"),
    showWeather = document.querySelector("#weather h1"),
    weatherPic = document.querySelector("#weather div"),
    temperature = document.querySelector("#temperature"),
    feelsLike = document.querySelector("#feels-like");
    
async function getWeather(e) {
    const keyword = document.querySelector("#keyword").value;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(keyword);
    const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=179428b368194d318d421509232011&q=${keyword}`, {mode: 'cors'});
    const weatherData = await response.json();
    console.log(weatherData);

    const city = keyword.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + keyword.slice(1);
    cityName.innerText = city;

    showWeather.innerText = weatherData.current.condition.text;
    const weatherImg = document.createElement("img");
    weatherImg.setAttribute("id", "weather-img");
    weatherImg.src = weatherData.current.condition.icon;

    const showTemp = document.createElement("span");
    const showFeelsLike = document.createElement("span");
    showTemp.innerText = weatherData.current.condition.temp_c;
    showFeelsLike.innerText = weatherData.current.condition.feelslike_c;
  
    weatherPic.appendChild(weatherImg);

    
    temperature.appendChild(showTemp);
    feelsLike.appendChild(showFeelsLike);
};

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", getWeather);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

        <header>

            <div id="logo"><img src="images/myweatherapp.png" alt="My Weather App"> 
            <h2>My Weather App</h2></div>
            <div id="search">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="keyword" name="search-term" placeholder="City name">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value=">>">
                </form>
            </div>
        </header>

        <section id="content">
            <div id="content-header">
                <h1>The weather in <span id="city">{Search for your city}</span> today!</h1>
                <div id="weather">
                    <div></div>
                    <h1></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="date"></p><p id="time"></p>

            <div id="weather-report">
                <div id="temperature"></div>
                <div id="feels-like"></div>


            </div>

        </section>

    </div>
```

EDIT: For some reason the icon showed when I pasted it into this code snippet thing but it doesn't show on browser. The other items still showed as undefined!

Comment: Could you simplify your code? Maybe just the call to get the weather from a place where it doesn't work for you? With minimal HTML and Javascript. Is it the icon in the response that is the problem?

Comment: Yes, the icon shows up as a broken image but the URL is in the HTML and opens the image when I click open in new tab.
Il try to simplify it.
Thanks

Comment: it is because this is the path of the icon in the response `//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png` and due to the `//` at the beginning the browser defaults to `file://` URI scheme.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica It defaults to the scheme of the page. It's standard practice to support both http and https. However if the document is served with file, that will be used.

Comment: ah true, you are right!

Comment: @Elizabeth have you tried it in different browsers though? maybe there's something wrong with Chrome (and some extension you might have installed)

Comment: @some So are you saying that if it is run from a server it will display properly?

Comment: Thanks
I uploaded to Github and the images are working now. As for the undefined, that was an error on my part. Thanks again.

Comment: @Elizabeth Yes. The missing protocol is a feature of a relative url. Just like you can have just `filename.ext`, or `/path/filename.ext` you can have `//host/path/filename.ext`.  If your page is served over https you want all your resources to be loaded over https, and if you server it over http you want your resources to be http as well. That's why it didn't work for you since you served your page over file. I saw the missing protocol, that's why I asked if it was the icon that was the problem. It was probably 20 years ago since I served a file over the file protocol, so I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

try: weatherImg.src = "https:" + weatherData.current.condition.icon;
for some reason the default is file:// and you are looking for https://

Best Regards.